# Permissions with posting messages to Teams via graph api

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm getting a 403 when I try to post a message in teams via postman.  It works via graph explorer with the same account.  Clearly I have a permissions issue but I can't for the life of me find the right check box.

My app is registered and approved by admin.  I got it approved by MS to make protected api calls as well for teams.

I can get a token on behalf of a user in postman, I can use that token to get the messages in a channel, but cannot post.

Here are the api permission:
[Delegated Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlVBD.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the URL you are attempting to call. And the scopes you granted the app. And the scopes in the token you received. (Decode the token at https://jwt.ms).

It is very difficult to help with no specifics provided in the question.

Comment: Could you please check if your access token has required permissoins using https://jwt.io/?